# 403 http code appears when I go to a certain website

Tags: centos, wget, curl, http

I wrote a PHP script to a particular site using a home computer for debugging. Script worked properly, when I tested it on a home computer. The script has stopped working when I deploy the script on the server (CentOS).

I thought, that I made a mistake when writing the script, and created [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323304/php-curl-dont-set-headers).

**Chuan Ma** suggested that the website administration blocked server IP. I wrote to the admins and they said that they do not block the IP.

**My problem is that I can not go to the site using the server.** I tried several tools for getting html of the site.

1. I have tried to use the browser. I deployed on my server [this script](https://webvpn.org/?lang=en) and went to the site as a real user. When I visit the site using the browser, I get an error (http code 403).
2. I have tried `curl` from the command line.

   ```
   server:~# curl http://4pda.ru/
   <html>
   <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
   <hr><center>nginx</center>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. I tried the utility `wget`.

   ```
   server:~# wget  http://4pda.ru --quiet -O -
   server:~#
   ```

I do not know what to do now. I would welcome any advice.

Answer (score 1):

`403 forbidden` means that the webserver is configured to not allow you to do what you're trying to do. In most cases, it's either of the following:

- The script does not have execute permissions on the server (i.e. it's uploaded with -rw-r--r-- instead of -rwxr-xr-x, or maybe -rwx------
- The script is in a directory that the server does not have access to due to the directory/file permissions
- The server is configured to not allow access to files in that directory (in this case, you need to look at the server's `httpd.conf`)

#### Edited with yet another potential reason

Another reason can be that the server is configured with mod_security, which may require a full set of HTTP headers. This is a protection against a lot of crack/dos attacks often used by script kiddies. If this is the case, make sure that your script sends the HTTP header

```
User-Agent: A suitable name for your script
```

If that doesn't help, you need to ask the server administrator for the site that's failing your script and ask them what their HTTP logs say.

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to clarify whether I have understood you. I have a server (VDS, CentOS). Using this server, I want to get the html code of a website. I use CURL (PHP) for this task. When I want to get, for example, the html code of the Google page, everything works correctly. When I want to get the html code of the site 4pda.ru, I get a 403 http response code. That is, the script works correctly in the general case, but it does not work for the site 4pda.ru.

Comment: OK, then I completely misunderstood you - I thought you meant that you were trying to access your own script. I think I may have an idea though; let me edit my answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer now. I have seen that particular issue several times as the place I work with is using mod_security, and about every three months I get some script developer asking me why their script doesn't work for our site.

Comment: Jenny D, thanks for the new answer. Unfortunately, I am sending identical user request headers. You're probably right, I have to again talk to the administrator.

Comment: Darn. It might be some other header they're requesting though - but yes, at this point all we have is guesses. I hope you get a good answer from your sysadmin!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the needed URL (I write google as an example):

```
wget --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/600.1.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.17" 'https://www.google.es'
```

Comment: Why would the website require a particular user agent?

Comment: To skip a header check in same cases like https. The goal is to obtain the same content as what you see in a normal Web browser

Comment: But the question already says "When I visit the site using the browser, I get an error (http code 403)."

Comment: HTTP 403 is returned when the client is not permitted access to the resource for some reason besides authentication. For instance: cookies, etc.

Comment: Possible causes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403#o403_substatus_error_codes_for_IIS